# How do I remove control points from imported curve in Maya?

Tags: 3d, graphics, models, maya

When I create a path from an Illustrator file, it adds extra control points for bezier handles for each point in the AI file, even though I don't drag out the handles in Illustrator.  All my points in the AI file are hard edges.

I can clean this up by using the merge vertex tool, but that takes a long time on each model.  Is there a way I can:

1. Select all the control points at once and delete the extra curve handle points
   OR
2. Import without the extra handle points and have only a flat polygon.

I'm importing the path as curves, because when I import as bevel it adds lots of extra geometry.  I'm new to Maya, but have taken several lessons, so please be gentle.